# Calculate in terms of f and r only

Tags: analysis

Let $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and define $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $u(x) = f(r)$, where $r = \lVert x\rVert_2$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Calculate
$$
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\right)^2
$$ in terms of $f$ and $r$ only.

I had no idea about this one.If someone would help me?

Answer (score 1):

For every $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$  and every nonzero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x)=f'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j}=\frac{x_j}{r}f'(r).
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x)\right)^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^2}{r^2}(f'(r))^2=\frac{1}{r^2}(f'(r))^2\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2}_{r^2}=(f'(r))^2.
$$

Comment: $r = \|x\|_2$ is a function of $x$, namely $r(x) = \sqrt{\sum_j x_j^2}$.

Comment: @DI... I used the chain rule

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to calculate $\|\nabla u\|^2$. Now use the chain rule to get $\nabla u = f'(r) \nabla r = f'(r)\frac{x}{r}$.